# TypeError: StyleSheet.create is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create some styles for my react component like this:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
 /*Pinout*/

 /*GPIO Shapre*/
 gpio_outer: {
   background: '#222222',
   borderRadius: 5,
   height: 26,
   width: 26,
 },
})
```

I'm adding it like

After compiling the code and try to run on the browser I get this from the browser console:

```
TypeError: StyleSheet.create is not a function
```

Do you know what can be happening? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

StyleSheet is a part of React-Native, not a part of regular ReactJS.  You can however instantiate a style object and use that like you would in RN.

```
render() {
  const style = {
    margin: '0.5em',
    paddingLeft: 0,
    listStyle: 'none'
  };

  return <ul style={style}>item</ul>;
}
```

A quick google search also led me to find a few react js libraries that give you the abstraction you're looking for.

- [Radium](http://projects.formidablelabs.com/radium/)
- [react-style](https://github.com/js-next/react-style)
- [Good info source](https://survivejs.com/react/advanced-techniques/styling-react/)

Answer (score 4):

You should import StyleSheet correctly from react-native. You probably haven't written it correctly. Check this one:

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you requiring `StyleSheet` properly?

You can try to check this tutorial https://www.toptal.com/ios/cold-dive-into-react-native-a-beginners-tutorial